# Related concept for iOS like "APK Expansion Files in Android"

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ipad

I'm expecting suggestions for the concept related to APK Expansion Files in Android.

Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 50MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

Does apple give any support like this?

In my case I have 180MB audio file, I don't want to keep that with app resource. After installation I want this download from APPLE store.

I can able to keep this in my server and download when app opens first time, but I would like to know is there any other way to supplement for iPA.

Thanks InAdvance.

Comment: Just for information.. You can't place registered and copy rights audio songs and/or videos within your project's ipa. App Store will reject your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size of your ipa could be up to 2GB. For sizes upper than 50mb will be downloaded through WiFi or from iTunes. ipa less than that could also be downloaded through 3G network.
Try to make your app size as minimum as possible as users don't really like apps with larger size..
Well there's no thing here in iOS like APK Extension Files in Android.. Everything is your one single ipa which is compressed form of your binaries and resources.

Comment: Yes I know the limit for iPa is upto 2GB. I want my app size should be below 20 MB for some reason. :) But I have 180MB resource :(

Comment: I don't whether it will be legal or not,, place your resources at some ftp server of your own.. and after installation of your app.. ask user to download resources. and then download them in background thread.

Comment: see answer of Mike Weller for more details :-)
He has suggested the same thing

Comment: can you suggest me any Apple documentation where it mention we cant use Apk Expansion

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't offer a facility for this specific use case.

You'll have to download the content when your app starts for the first time. Remember to store it in the caches directory or set the "do not backup" flag on the files. This is according to Apple's guidelines and required for app review. If you store it in the Caches directory, iOS may decide to delete the data when disk space is low, so be prepared to download it again if it doesn't exist when your app starts.

Unless you're using in-app purchases and targetting iOS 6 users only, you'll have to host it on your own servers. In-app purchases cannot be free.